# Saving users scores and favorites in Firestore Database

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am working in a small project that uses Firestore database as a backend. I explain about the database so it is understood what I need:

Basically I have a collection that contains a list of documents where each one of them represent a game. For each game I have the name, cover image, info, category, etc.

I also have a collection of the users, where I have the specific UID for each user (retrieved from the auth section), email, etc.

What I want now is to save the score that some user may have in some of these games, as well as the favorite games that the user could save. What I don't get to understand is how to create the connection between the users and the games. For example, I thought that I should save the users score creating a collection within each document(game) in the first collection that mentioned. But when I create this collection with ID "scores" it asks me for the first document where I have to facilitate an ID (if not automatic) and then I don't know how to proceed.

I have read also that I would have to create additional collections in the root folder like "favorites" or "scores" specifying the UID of the user but, how do I connect the user UID, the score, and game which the user got that score from?

I hope I explained myself properly. Thanks.

Comment: It sounds like you could use a general tutorial in nosql database design.  I suggest watching this video series. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=haMOUb3KVSo

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, I agree with Doug's comment above. The Firestore tutorial videos are a great resource!

In terms of connecting data to your user, you have some options. You can either:

1. Create sub-collections under each user. Such as `/users/{user_id}/favorites`. Favorites could be a sub-collection or an array of game_ids depending on your use case.
2. Store a `userID` field in the documents in a top level "scores" or "favorites" collection. Then you can query for scores in the /scores collection by adding a `where userID == {user_id}` clause to your query of the /scores collection.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have been watching some of the videos but my lack of knowledge will require more reading and experimenting. I understand how to connect users with their scores, but I don't quite understand how to connect that score with the different "documents" from the collection (each game will have a different score for different users).